# When Does Google Photos Choose To Backup My Images

Tags: iphone, applications, google-photos

So I have downloaded the Google Photos app and selected free unlimited back up plan.

It seems to display a recycle bin next to images that haven't been backed up.

Now could someone explain how and when the app chooses when to back up photos?

Do I have to have the the application open to backup photos or not?
Is there a way to force sync this on my computer maybe?

It seems very inconsistent and there seems to be no sync button that I have found.

Comment: Do you have background app refresh on for the application?

Comment: @bret7600 is that under settings? Found it.  Yes

Comment: Ok... I'll admit to having issues with it. I typically just leave my phone / iPad unlocked all night plugged in and allowing it to back up. After it is done, it is usually fine. However: Live Photos sometimes back up separately as do videos because it is more work for it to process these. P.S. to check the status, tap the assistant page. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mac [desktop uploader](https://photos.google.com/apps) actually works really well in the background!

I leave the iPhone app open and let it upload everything periodically although it does seem to upload when I leave the app open in the background.